# How I can get the EC2 Instance Name using C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Dears,
I wrote a code to List Instance Proparties and Display using C#

```
AmazonEC2Client amazonEC2Client = new AmazonEC2Client("id", "password", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))           
DescribeInstancesRequest describeInstancesRequest = new DescribeInstancesRequest();
DescribeInstancesResponse describeInstancesResponse = amazonEC2Client.DescribeInstances(describeInstancesRequest);
List<Reservation> result = describeInstancesResponse.Reservations;
```

then I Can get Values of EC2 Attributes using this code:

```
               foreach (var reservation in result)
                {
                    foreach (var instance in reservation.Instances)
                    {

                        instance.InstanceId;
                    }
                }
```

I need to get the Name Proparty
Advise Please
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you have retrieved InstanceId, all the information which you can receive about an instance is listed in this [API doc.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TEC2Instance.html)

Name is basically a Tag, so look into `instance.Tags`

Comment: Thank you so much,, i can get it use [instance.Tags[0].Value], but i need to use it without indicate index,,Tag[0]

Comment: `instance.Tags.Where(x=>x.Key == "Name").Value`

Comment: @ Rumesh Eranga,, thank you for your efforts, bwt That dosn't work

Comment: Btw you should be able to write a LINQ query to get the value correctly. instead of accessing array index. It is a c# generic collection. From AWS Perspective I believe I have given the correct answer.

Comment: ThanQ you,, It's True :) :)